# How does one search for flights with miles? Or is it simply a post-selection operation?

Tags: air-travel, loyalty-programs

I have started to accumulate a few decent miles with some airlines.  In the past, I've merely used miles to reduce the cost - choose a flight, apply points, voila.

However, I was wondering if there was a way to specify your miles into a search (like kayak) - say, enter, x Delta miles, x Qantas miles, x BA miles, and hit go and see what gets found with the 'discount' applied?

Just a random idea that I wondered if it might exist.

Comment: If you know the airline, calling them will allow them to search which flight arrangements will bring you to your destination using miles. I've never heard of a service that does what you suggest, and I wouldn't expect there to be any, given that I've never really seen advertised which flights are still available via miles on booking sites.

Comment: @Jonas - it's weird, on flightfox.com, there's a place to provide for miles, and many people seem to include them and experts provide deals based on them, so I assumed there must be a way.  Unless these are only the experts who are actual travel agents, which would be unfortunate :/

Comment: I think it should be possible. For example with the Star Alliances miles, there is an official search tool on www.miles-and-more.com that allows you to do exactly that.

Comment: @RoflcoptrException: Thanks, I wasn't aware of that tool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[MileWise](https://secured.milewise.com/) sounds similar to what you are looking for. It presents fares in cash/miles/points, and lets you specify how many points you have in various award accounts. The results are ranked via "the best ways to pay based on your rewards".

A major drawback is that the service cannot be used for American, Delta, or Southwest.